# Angular Universal / Node: Backend not accessing session. Creating new on each reload

Tags: angular7, angular-universal

I am using session based authentication in my Angular Universal app. Problem is when http request is made from Angular app, backend (node.js) doesn't access the ongoing session, but creates new. You might think this is because cors, but the thing is, the first initial load only doesn't access session. So when I open up my app on page that has resolver or guard, that is making http request. That http request is going to create new session. Then navigating to other pages in app, it all works. http requests made after initial load will access the session. If I start from page that has no resolver/guards and then navigate to page that has and makes http request, this request will access to session.

Here is how my session is setup in `index.js`:

```
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);
app.use(
    session({
        key: 'sessionStorage',
        store: sessionStore,
        secret: config.get('demoSess'), 
        saveUninitialized: false, 
        resave: false,
        name: 'demo',
        cookie: { 
            maxAge: 60000,
            secure: false
        },
    })
)

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: [
        'http://localhost:4200'
    ], 
    credentials: true
    })
);
```

And this how http request is made from frontend:

```
this.http.get(environment.apiUrl+'/server/page/auth', {withCredentials: true});
```

Is this how it should be? Backend runs on port 8080 and frontend 4200.

In `app.module.ts`, I have written `TransferHttpCacheModule`. If I remove it, I can see from backend, when I console log something, that first http request is made twice- first one doesn't access session and then second one does. So if I was to `console.log(req.session.userId)` in `/server/page/auth`, I would get `undefined` and `1` on next line. As I read, something like this was normal and to get around it, `transferstate` comes to into play, but as I understand `TransferHttpCacheModule` is basically easy way to do the `transferstate`. I tried also with writting the `transferstate` into resolver and outcomes was same- one request is only made, but that request wont access session.

I am hoping I am missing something when I am making http request from frontend or my session/cors is missing something. At this point I am running out of idea what to check or test, any hint what to check out is welcoming.

Answer (score 1):

So I started to build around my authentication in Angular to use `localStorage`. I ran there into problem and while searching for solution I ran into tutorial talking something about `isPlatformBrowser`. So I started thinking, maybe Angular Universal in some way is making two request, but these two request are different and I need to eliminate one of them. So I ended up wrapping my http request with `if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {  }` and so far it seems I got my problem fixed.